# show all the roles with Display Name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a plugin for wordpress. I am  adding some new roles with below code and I want to show them in a  control with their Display name... but it shows the role name ... I dont know how to get the Display name of role.

adding role code:

```
add_role( 'jobholder', "موظف", array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true ) );
add_role( 'manager',  "مدیر", array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true ) );
```

geting roles list:

```
<select id="role_user" name="role_user">                                
<option value="0"><?php _e("select Role","creat_mysite"); ?>...</option>
<?php
      global $wp_roles;
      $all_roles = $wp_roles->roles;
      foreach($all_roles as $role_name => $role_info){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $role_name ?>"><?php echo $role_name; ?></option>         
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do a `var_dump` of `$wp_roles`? That way, you'd know what is the data structure of it and you could know how to print whatever you need.

If `$wp_roles` wouldn't have the display name of role, you'll have to query directly to get the data you needed.